# $_POST without values

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to send data with POST, but the result is `array(0)` when the `var_dump` function is called.

Other forms using post method with AJAX results on a correct value of the variables, and the HTML does not work.

Why could this be happening?

The form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
      </head>

      <body>
      <form target="_new" enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' action="include/php/produtos/romaneio/prueba.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" value="12" id="a" />
      <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
```

The php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <? var_dump($_POST);
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why are you var-dumping `$GLOBALS`? You should be var-dumping `$_POST` (or at the very least `$_REQUEST`) [for debug purposes]. Unless you have register globals enabled (which I would **highly** advise **against**).

Comment: @Brad: I'd also recommend against `$GLOBALS` here, not least because it's JIT-initialised. However, register globals has nothing to do with it: [`$GLOBALS` includes `$_POST` anyway](http://codepad.org/9Tj25yeq).

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Agreed, i just get worried when I see people use `$GLOBALS`, in any scenario. :shrug:

Comment: "Other posts with AJAX work fine, and the HTML does not work" I didn't get this bit. Stop using the meaningless and useless word "work"

Comment: I dumped th $GLOBALS seaching for some other or reason where the POSTO could be,but you are right I should use the $_POST var for this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of form elements will only be added to `$_POST` if the elements are named using `name=`. So, add `name="d"` instead of `id="d"`.

Comment: Thank you both for the answer

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to give your `input` a `name`; the form thus has no submittable content.

```
<form target="_new" enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' action="include/php/produtos/romaneio/prueba.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" value="12" name="a" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

(The `id` attribute is for other stuff, localised to working with the DOM through, say, Javascript or CSS.)